# function to sum all the matrix elements and return sum

Tags: function, matrix

> subscripted value is neither an array nor pointer nor vector at line sum+=matrix[i][j]

```
int matrix(int matrix[],int m, int n)  //function
{
      int sum=0,i,j;           //to add the matrix elements
      for(int i = 0;i< m ; i ++)
      {
         for(int j=0;j<n; j ++)
         {
```

> Blockquote

```
            sum+=matrix[i][j];   //error
         }
      }
    return sum
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt you be passing two dimensional array  to your function ?? Like below.
int matrix(int matrix[][],int m, int n)
 Here are some examples already. in java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638550/finding-sum-of-two-dimensional-array-java

Comment: Basic question pointed to some existing answers already in  comments for the user.